# Which automated theorem provers can output proofs in natural language?

Tags: theorem-proving

Most automated theorem provers are based on resolution, and produce proofs that are hard to read for a human. I wonder if there are provers which can generate human readable proofs, either in natural language, or in at least in form that is intelligible for humans.
I am aware of : *A fully automatic problem solver with human-style output* M. Ganesalingam, W. T. Gowers
Are there any other provers ?

I could not find other references in the above paper.

Comment: ACL2's output is designed to be in a narrative style: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/

Comment: I am more interested in ATP than proof assistants.